# How to use Linq to compare two column in Sql

Tags: c#, linq

Sql Table:

```
ID      User        Pass
1       John        09o0s
2       Jim         bd09d
```

C#:

```
string u = the user name provided by someone;
string p = the password provided by someone;

List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

bool trueor =  list.Any(user => user.Equals(strU));
```

How can I use Linq to see if the username provided has an entry and if it does, is the password provided match the username.

Comment: This requires exactly two of the basic LINQ functions covered in tutorials.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try this for your deleted question if it's still not working: https://jsfiddle.net/dotspencer/3xnmn7np/8/

Comment: @spencer.sm Thank you. I almost had something similar using `map` function but your is simpler and shorter...

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `&&` operator to compare both the username and password:

```
bool isValidUser = list.Any(x => x.User == u && x.Pass == p);
```

By the way with your current design it looks like you are storing the user passwords in plain text inside your database. This is something that you should not be doing but rather you should only be storing the hashes and the salt. So the proper algorithm would be this:

```
string u = the user name provided by someone;
string p = the password provided by someone;

// I have no idea what this dt variable is, but I assume for this example
// that it is an entity framework context that returns a users table with the
// following columns: ID, User, PasswordSalt and PasswordHash
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

bool isValidUser = false;
var user = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.User == u); // the username must be unique
if (user != null)
{
    string actualHash = CalculateHash(p, user.PasswordSalt);
    isValidUser = actualHash == u.PasswordHash;
}

return isValidUser;
```

So as you can see in this example the proper implementation is to store the Username, Salt and the Password hash in your database. Then compare the calculated hash against the value from the db to validate if the user has entered correct credentials.

Comment: `.User` how do I get that? Thanks. Ohhhh this is only a test and the password won't be plain text of course.

Comment: No idea, your ORM would probably provide it assuming you have properly configured it. Basically if you are using Entity Framework you would get the same properties on the User object as columns in the database. In your question you seem to have provided some `dt` variable, which I guess, you are probably the only person on this planet that knows what it represents.

Comment: I ended up using a `Dictionary`. Populated the dictionary and compared it that way... much simpler. Thank you.

Comment: `.User` is the column name?

Comment: Yes, in my example it represents the username which should be unique in your users table.

Comment: I used a Dictionary in C# to achieve what I needed. Thank you